# Best strategy to handle broken network connections?

Tags: android, synchronization, client-server, networkstream

i want to keep my app in sync with the Server. The communication between client (android app) and server is handled through JSON Objects / HTTP. What is the best strategy if the connection is not available anymore? It is important that the user can continue his work with the app. Does there even exist frameworks for such sync-problems?

i thought about a queue of transactions?! Any reccomendations or experiences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fetching... I once wrote a caching URL manager that would load read the JSON from reply from the server and write it to the SD Card.  When if the user did another request for the same URL a short time later, the URL manager would simply return the cached json from the filesystem as the JSON reply.  This made the communication code somewhat transparent, in that I was always dealing with JSON replies, whether or not they were cached or real time.

For sending information to the server, you could write all information to the database, and use a background service that pushes the data to the server.  That way the UI will always succeed in writing the information and your sync service would push data if there was a network connection.  Using a Service you can simply pass the data in the Service intent and it can worry about the writing to db and syncing, etc.

Comment: By server side errors, do you mean client to server communication errors where the request to server fails... or do you mean errors that happen on the server itself?

Comment: i thought about semantic errors on serverside. For example when a user creates an object on client side, works with this object and during the sync an error emerges that the object e.g. already was created by another user.

Comment: I think in that case, you 2 options... 1. Tell the user they have to re-submit and overwrite the existing record.  2. Do a merge of their data into the existing record.  If you are doing #1, and you've submitted the record in the background, then the responses could update your local copy of the data with the error and push a notification to the user that their data was not transmitted sucessfully. (ie, use notification bar).  When the select the notification, then they are brought to their editing screen with the message and the user can submit again, and overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/aesync.html

i think this is what i will use in my next project :)